# Android Studio smooth scrolling in Editor

Tags: android-studio

Sorry for a simple question,
but I can not find the solution myself.
I just switched from PC to Mac Android Studio.
And one thing bothers me a lot - it is scrolling in the editor.
I don't know how to correctly explain this:
Scrolling in Editor is not smooth like on PC,
when you scroll here it all the time adjusts the bottom (and the top) line to fit the bottom (and the top) of the editor,
and it seems like scrolling lags.
I tried explore all the preferences,
including options in Editor->General->Scrolling
But it has no effect

Comment: I bought new Macbook pro

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because computer/hardware performance has nothing* to do with programming.

Comment: what a hell hardware???

Comment: @Shark - No, it involves a tool directly used for programming

Comment: I am talking that Scrolling in the editor works like a ViewPager and i want it to be like a ScrollView if saying in development terms

Comment: @cricket_007 feel free to reopen if it gets closed.

Comment: @Shark do you think this question is off topic? Can you see the tags? Also this has nothing with the hardware. I think you don't even read it

Comment: Hey now, kids, play nice. On a serious note, the Mac scrolling just takes awhile to get used to.

Comment: the tags are off, since the question itself really has nothing to do with `intellij-idea` or to better say - the question does not quite belong in the same group as other `intellij-idea` questions. I think I read it fine, and apparently - 3 more people think you wrote it bad as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Hope it will help you my friend !

Comment: i tried this options, but it has no effect

Comment: I hope it will surely help you. Use this plugin. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6274?pr=clion

Comment: Thank you, this helps me

Comment: Welcome always @Androider.